# How to update the Info-default-directory-list dynamically

Tags: emacs

While running Emacs, I would like to update a specific manual by using a new path to a new version of that manual.

What I do so far is to update the variable `Info-default-directory-list`, then I kill all info-buffers. But on the next <kbd>C-h i</kbd> I still get back the old manual. So it seems that there is some state left somewhere. I would like to avoid re-launching Emacs, since this happens quite frequently to me.

So how can I do this without restarting Emacs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should update `Info-directory-list` too. From the help of `Info-default-directory-list`:

```
Once Info is started, the list of directories to search
comes from the variable `Info-directory-list'.
This variable `Info-default-directory-list' is used as the default
for initializing `Info-directory-list' when Info is started, unless
the environment variable INFOPATH is set.
```